# Parse Int Crashes my program and yes I have my xml iput type set to number

Tags: java, android, crash, parseint

When I run my app everything works fine until I press a button that runs a method called calculate() and the parse int crashes the program.

This is a simplified version of my problem. When I press the button "calculate" it runs the method calculate(). However, it crashes. No error is given it just crashes in the Emulator.

JAVA CODE FOR MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

public void calculate(View view) {
    EditText length_find = findViewById(R.id.feet);
    EditText pounds_find = findViewById(R.id.pounds);
    int length = Integer.parseInt(length_find.getText().toString());
    int pounds = Integer.parseInt(pounds_find.getText().toString());

    int sum = length + pounds;

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sum, LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

XML CODE:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/calculate"
    android:layout_width="158dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="113dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="113dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
    android:onClick="calculate"
    android:text="Calculate"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pounds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="86dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="#'s"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/feet"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/feet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="86dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Feet"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pounds" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify what happens on some unexpected exception, you can do the following:

```
 public void calculate(View view) {
     EditText length_find = findViewById(R.id.feet);
     EditText pounds_find = findViewById(R.id.pounds);

     try {
         int length = Integer.parseInt(length_find.getText().toString());
         int pounds = Integer.parseInt(pounds_find.getText().toString());

         int sum = length + pounds;
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sum, LENGTH_LONG).show();
     catch(Exception ex) {
         Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

 }
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for the help and it worked but now it's doing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967597/my-try-catch-function-wont-work-as-expected

Comment: This answer just is a trick to see what exception you are receiving, but if you want to know what really happens then  you should debug your code... And analyze what value is throwing the exception or what value is empty...