# My try catch function won't work as expected

Tags: java, android, if-statement, try-catch

My program is supposed to take the given value and find the other value with it. However, my try catch statement doesn't seem to be working. It never does the first 2 if statements which are the most essential parts of the program. The 3rd one does work when you input both values. Thanks in Advance.

```
        public void calculate(View view) {
    EditText length_find = findViewById(R.id.feet);
    EditText pounds_find = findViewById(R.id.pounds);

    try {
        //int length_int = Integer.parseInt(length_find.getText().toString());
        //int pounds_int = Integer.parseInt(pounds_find.getText().toString());

        double d = .29;
        //double length = length_int;
        //double pounds = pounds_int;
        double w = 24.5 / 12;
        double h = .002 / 12;

        //This Calculates if Pounds are given
        if ((length_find).getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Given Pounds", LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int pounds_int = Integer.parseInt(pounds_find.getText().toString());
            double pounds = pounds_int;
            double v = pounds / d;
            double length = v / w / h;
            final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.length_show);
            mTextView.setText((int) length);
        }


        //This Calculates if Length is given
        if ((pounds_find).getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Given Length", LENGTH_LONG).show();
          int lenght_int = Integer.parseInt(length_find.getText().toString());
          double length = lenght_int;
          double v = length * w * h;
          double answer_pounds = v * d;
          final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pound_show);
          mTextView.setText((int) answer_pounds);
        }
        if((pounds_find).getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && (length_find).getText().toString().trim().length() > 0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Whata hell you need me for mate!", LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: *Curious:* `length() <= 0` When do you expect `length()` to be negative?

Comment: negative length() of `string`??? that can never happen so you are not having a problem, your logic is just not right.

Comment: Yea my mistake I see what you guys are saying, however it still has the same problem if I switch <= to ==.

Answer (score 1):

As i understood,

```
(pounds_find).getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0
```

or

```
(length_find).getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0
```

is true only when user hasn't input anything. if he has, then 3rd "if" execute as expected. But when user hasn't input anything then

```
int length_int = Integer.parseInt(length_find.getText().toString());
int pounds_int = Integer.parseInt(pounds_find.getText().toString());
```

cannot be done. because it is empty. I think that's the case here. If that isn't please let me know. If i'm wrong sorry. That's what i understood from here. If you could debug and be specific about scenario or exception if it throw any, that would be more helpful

Comment: Ok, I've done what you said, however, I still run into the same problem. I've updated the code so you can take a look. I commented out the old code.

Comment: Thanks by the way for the help

Comment: Also, i'm  fairly new to programming and have only done 1 semester of a highschool class.  It peaked my intrest and so I've spent my Winter Break doing it. So i don't know how to debug.

Comment: Don't worry, your doing so good for 1 semester. you'll learn how to debug pretty soon, but until then

Comment: what you have to do is write a if condition and check whether the inputs are empty, if they are make toast, else then directly parse them to double and assign it to a global double variable. then within the code deal with that variable. do not use pounds_find and length_find, that's more like a tradition.

Comment: I found what my problem was. It couldn't change the text to a double so I just had to convert the double into a String.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Anytime Anthony, Happy Coding